# Core Data Sync - Tracking Deleted Objects

Tags: iphone, mysql, ios, ipad, core-data

I'm setting up a basic sync service for an iPad application I'm developing. The goal is to have data consistent throughout several instances of the iPad app, as well as having a read-only version of the data on the web, hence rolling a custom solution.

The current flow is this:

- Each entity has a 'created', 'modified' and 'UUID' field which are automatically updated by Core Data
- On sync, each entity with a created or modified date after the last sync date is serialised into JSON and sent to the server
- The server persists any changes to a MySQL database using the client-generated UUIDs as PKs (if there's a conflict, it just uses the most recently modified entity as the 'true' version, nothing fancy there) and sends back any updated entities to the client
- The client then merges these changes back into its Core Data DB

This all seems to be working fine. My problem is how to track deleted objects using this method? I'm guessing I can add a 'deleted' flag to each entity and set this whenever a client deletes something, I can then push that change to the server with the rest of the sync data. Once the sync is complete then the client can actually delete these entities. My questions are:

- Can I override Core Data's delete methods to automatically set this flag?
- Will this require keeping all deleted entities indefinitely on the server? We'll have no way  of knowing when every client has synced and actually deleted each entity (I'm not currently tracking client instances)
- Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about you keep a delta history table with UUID and created/updated/deleted field, maybe with a revision number for each update? So you keep a small check list of changes since your last successful sync.

That way, if you delete an object you could add an entry in the delta history table with the deleted UUID and mark it deleted. Same with created and updated objects, you only need to check the delta table to see what items you the server needs to delete, update, create, etc. You could even store every revision on the server to support rolling back to a previous version in the future if you feel like it.

I think a revision number is better than relying on client's clock that could potentially be changed manually.

You could use NSManagedObjectContext's insertedObjects, updatedObjects, deletedObjects methods to create the delta objects before every save procedure :)

My 2 cents

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I've adopted a hybrid approach for now that's doing the sync as I described in the question but now maintains a table of deleted objects as well. I'll look to migrate to the fully delta'd system in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not you have to keep deleted objects on the server or not totally depends on your needs.  You will need a deleted flag locally to mark as deleted for the sync, maybe also on the server depending on your desire to roll back.

I have taken care of this problem a few ways before.  Here is one possibility:

When a client deletes something, just mark it to be deleted locally and delete from the server during the sync (at which point you can purge from core data).  When other clients request to access that data, send back an HTTP 404 because you dont have the object any more.  At that point the client can delete the entity locally.  Now if a client requests a list of things and this object has been deleted, it will just be missing from the list of things he gets back so you can detect that and delete it. I do that in a client by creating an array of object IDs when I get a response from the server and deleting any local objects that don't have those IDs.

We have a deleted field on the server, but just to have the ability to roll back in case something is deleted by accident.

Of course you could return deleted objects to the client so they know to delete but if you don't want to keep a copy on the server, you would have to make some assumption that the clients would all update within a time frame.  Then you could garbage collect after that time frame has expired.

I don't really like that solution though.  If your data is too heavy to ask for all the objects for a complete sync, you could use your current merge strategy for creating and updating, and then run a separate call to check for deleted items.  That call could simply ask for all IDs that the client should have on the device.  It could delete the ones that don't exist.  OR it could send all IDs on the client and get back a list of IDs to delete.

I think you have to provide more details about the nature of the data if you want a more opinionated suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question: You can design this so that the server doesn't have to keep deleted records around, if you want to. Let each app know if a given piece of data (based on its UUID) is stored on the server (e.g. add an existsOnServer property or similar). This starts out false when a new item is created in the app, but is set to true once  it has been synced to the server for the first time. That way, if the app tries to sync later, but the UUID is not found, you can differentiate the two cases: If existsOnServer is false, then then this item is newly created and should be synced to the server, but if it is true then it can be taken to mean that it was already on the sever before, but has now been deleted, so you can delete it in the app too.

I'd probably argue against this approach, since it seems more error prone to me (I imagine a database or connection error incorrectly being interpreted as a deletion) and keeping records around on your server would usually not be a big deal, but it is possible. The "delta-approach" suggested by dzeikei could be used at the same time, so an update to a record that does not exist on the server signifies that it was deleted, while an insert does not.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [Cross-Platform Data Synchronization by Dan Grover](http://iphone2009.crowdvine.com/talk/presentation_file/5104/Grover_Syncing.pdf) if you haven't. It's a very well written paper regarding synchronization and iOS.

About your questions:

1. You can avoid deleting a file in Core Data and set a 'deleted flag': just update the file instead of deleting it. You could make your own 'deleting' method that actually would call and update the flag on the record.
2. Keep always a last_sync and a last_updated for each record on the server and on each client. This way you'll always know when someone did change something anywhere and if that change was synced or not against the 'truth database'.
3. Keeping track of deleted files is a hard thing to do, I guess the best way to do it is keeping track of the history of syncs for each table, but is a difficult task. The easiest way, using this 'truth-database' kind of configuration is to flag the files, so that way yes, you should keep the data on the server as well as on the client.

Answer (score -3):

during synchronization of data between tow table  some records or deleted when the table rows are same. and when the rows are different the correctly synchronized, i used this Code click here on image

[image]

Comment: Hi Gulsherkhan, please do not include images of code, include code instead.